# Hosting Server Blacklisted / must use SMTP however mail going to SPAM from Contact Form

Tags: php, email, contacts

Before I was using a mail function in PHP on my contact form.

However my hosting company is now blacklisted which is a real pain.

So now the goal is to use SMTP.

The code below works but kick everything to spam.

Please do not give me a negative for asking a question. I have checked on Google and read other sources. I am looking for help.

```
//STARTING HERE
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
  ->setUsername('example@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('example')
  ;

$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('contact@example.example' => 'Contact form'))
  ->setTo(array('123@gmail.com', '123@123.com' => 'Author leon')) 
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;


$result = $mailer->send($message);
if ($result)
echo "Success " . $result; // if 1 one email has been sent, if 2 then two emails hes been sent.
else
echo "Error";
?>
```

EMAIL HEADER

```
Delivered-To: example@example.com
Received: by 10.204.231.11 with SMTP id jo11cs300466bkb;
        Wed, 1 Feb 2012 08:11:30 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.180.77.228 with SMTP id v4mr19801267wiw.2.1328112690201;
        Wed, 01 Feb 2012 08:11:30 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <contact@example.example.tv>
Received: from rweb2-v.000025.net (rweb2-v.000025.net. [89.238.128.229])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id u2si18187663weq.118.2012.02.01.08.11.29
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Wed, 01 Feb 2012 08:11:29 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 89.238.128.229 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of contact@example.example.tv) client-ip=89.238.128.229;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 89.238.128.229 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of example@example.tv) smtp.mail= example@example.tv
Received: from pib by rweb2-v.000025.net with local (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <example@example.tv>)
    id 1RscmP-000iR1-1g; Wed, 01 Feb 2012 16:11:29 +0000
To: example@example, Author leon <example@example.com>
Subject: Wonderful Subject
Message-ID: <1328112689.4f296431088d2@example.tv>
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 16:11:29 +0000
From: Contact form < example@example.tv>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - rweb2-v.000025.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - example.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [1144 1145] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain – example@example.tv

Here is the message itself
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is? What does this "The code below works but kick everything to spam." mean?

Comment: He is saying that the emails he sends go to spam folders of his recipients. See my answer below.

Comment: What do your mails look like? Just like the example here?

Comment: Blacklisting is blacklisting. Normally it's done by plain IP address, so changing your method of mail delivery won't really matter.

Comment: More importantly, what do the email HEADERS look like? SpamCop/SpamAssassin don't put as much weight on the contents of the email as the content supplied in the headers.

Comment: @Barry Chapman - Please have a look above, this is the info in the email which is in the SPAM box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution what found, after removing a `//` of these from the code it worked.

So the question is can you have HTML inside you email?

Comment: You can send HTML in emails, but be sure to send the correct content type as text/html in the headers.

Comment: Your paste of headers above says otherwise:

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: @Barry Chapman - aaa right... I will have to have a look through and check... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Getting blacklisted is a pain, but there are certain steps you can take to help alleviate this:

- Set up Reverse DNS (RDNS) - talk to your provider
- Configure DKIM (Domain-Key Identified Mail)
- Set up SPF Records (For spam filters)

Taking these steps will adjust your 'spam score' and may aid your mail getting to your targets mailbox. Other than that, use a service like SendGrid to deliver your emails.

Comment: What I am saying is, it's not a code problem. It is a server/transport problem. You will undoubtedly need to talk to your hosting provider admins

Comment: Really, it is not the code at all.... But I thought if I use SMTP then I and not relying on the hosting company.

Comment: You can SMTP using whomever you want. That is why I suggested using SendGrid. Heck, you can even use Gmail for SMTP relay. If you send it through a trusted third party like that, you would most likely have no problem whatsoever. It is the IP of your server that is the trouble.

Comment: Ok.. great..... so we can get a solution.. I am using SMTP - GMAIL... however there must be something not right... as the emails go to the spam box....

Comment: @Arthor You are sending mail from domain xxx using SMTP server gmail.com That might be your problem

Comment: @PeeHaa - there is nothing wrong with doing this. I have done this on several sites without issue.

Comment: What about the reverse DNS issue when using gmail's SMTP server. Wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @PeeHaa - the ReverseDNS, SPF, and DKIM would only be necessary if he wanted to use his own server for mail transport. Using a relay server will take care of that themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting company is blacklisted you first need to find out what caused it.

Most blacklists work with an IP address. You can [check whether you are blacklisted](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check) on some sites.

Here you find out what 'providers' have blacklisted you and why. If you know why you are blacklisted you should takes measures so that it doesn't occur anymore. Or if it is outside your control you have to notify your hosting company and let them fix it ASAP. Most blacklists allow you to remove it (for a fee) or wait until the blacklist is removed. However if it is a serious hosting company they will do anything possible to remove it. Because other clients of it will have the same problem at start nagging right now.

Comment: There reason I want to go through the SMTP route is that in the future the server can become blocked. However with you SMTP, as long as everything is correct and you conform, then SMTP is a better way to go.

Comment: @Arthor is it shared hosting btw?